# NBA Seconds Left in Quarter Transform to Seconds left in Game

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns ("Quarter" and "Sec Left"). Here is how it looks for visualization purposes:

```
Quarter         SecLeft
1                 720
1                 718
.
.
2                 720
2                 716
.
.
3                 720
3                 715
```

Here is how I would like my columns to look like:

```
Quarter          SecLeft
1                 2880
1                 2878
.
.
2                 2160
2                 2156
.
.
3                 1440
3                 1435
```

So, in essence, I would just like to be able to transform the Seconds left column so that it is seconds left in the game rather than the number of seconds left in each quarter. If anyone has any ideas on how I can do this it would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: 720 seconds each quarter 2880 seconds total in the whole game

Comment: Something like `df['SecLeftGame'] = ((4-df$Quarter) * (60*12)) + df$SecLeft` this maybe? It's not entirely clear what you want and how long a quarter is. This would be for NBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just a mathematical operation.

Given you data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Quarter  SecLeft
1        720
1        718
2        720
2        716
3        720
3        715", header = TRUE)
```

Just do the following:

```
df$SecLeft <- df$SecLeft + (4-df$Quarter)*720
df

#>   Quarter SecLeft
#> 1       1    2880
#> 2       1    2878
#> 3       2    2160
#> 4       2    2156
#> 5       3    1440
#> 6       3    1435
```